# Why value field type date elasticsearch not same in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i want post data to elasticsearch with PHP Client Elasticsearch, but in value field date elasticsearch not same in kibana.

in elasticsearch dateutc: 2017-09-25 12:00:00

```
{
    "_index" : "weatherstation",
    "_type" : "weather",
    "_id" : "AV63xebkYyaraTOZkf0i",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "ID" : "LA",
      "tempf" : 9.0,
      "humidity" : 9,
      "dewptf" : 9.0,
      "windchillf" : 9.0,
      "winddir" : 9,
      "windspeedmph" : 9.0,
      "windgustmph" : 9.0,
      "rainin" : 9.0,
      "dailyrainin" : 9.0,
      "weeklyrainin" : 9.0,
      "monthlyrainin" : 9.0,
      "yearlyrainin" : 9.0,
      "solarradiation" : 9.0,
      "indoortemp" : 9.0,
      "UV" : 9,
      "indoortempf" : 9.0,
      "indoorhumidity" : 9,
      "baromin" : 0.0,
      "lowbatt" : 0,
      "softwaretype" : "0",
      "action" : "0",
      "realtime" : 0,
      "rtfreq" : 0,
      "dateutc" : "2017-09-25 12:00:00",
      "password" : "9"
    }
  }
```

in kibana [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5bkm.png)

Comment: That's a formatted date. Look at the JSON source, what do you see?

Comment: i see in format table kibana value date is not same in format json. is it any problem with utc format?

Comment: What do you see in the JSON tab of that document?

Comment: @Val in json tab value dateutc is 2017-09-25 12:00:00. i think is a format date in kibana

Comment: Yes, you can change that format in the Settings tab: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html